# Internal Server Error with Multiple Tags

Tags: 7, views

When creating a Drupal view that filters based on multiple tags, I'm getting the following error when I click preview:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging
>   information follows. Path:
>   /admin/structure/views/view/breakfast_things/preview/page_1/ajax
>   StatusText: Internal Server Error ResponseText:

And the following error when I hit save:

> Notice: Undefined property: Drupal\views\ManyToOneHelper::$query in
>   Drupal\views\ManyToOneHelper->add_filter() (line 312 of
>   core/modules/views/lib/Drupal/views/ManyToOneHelper.php).

Here is a screenshot of my page (this was after I clicked save)

[image]

If I keep everything the same but only use one tag, like eggs, then it works perfectly fine. Anyone know what's wrong here? I'm trying to create a view that will show all posts about eggs, spam, and other breakfast items.

Comment: look at logs of your site: error 500 maybe because of luck amount of RAM.
"Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted"

Answer (score 0):

SK , When you choose tag field in sort criteria, you will get two options Dropdown and Autocomplete. Choose Dropdown . This should fix your problem.

Comment: Choosing the Dropdown and selecting both tags makes the second error go away, but the Internal Server Error remains. EDIT: Actually scratch that, after saving a second time the 2nd error appears again.